# How to align image left and text right in a table effectively?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm showing a member who has a higher rank. Based on that, I have to show the user image along with the username.
but I'm not able to align the image and text efficiently..**The problem is some username consists of a longer number of characters. As a result, the username showed in a zig-zag position.**.

so far, I've tried

```html
<table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed"  class="table  table-striped text-center">
      <thead class='bg-dark' style='background-color: 3658DE'>
      <tr>
        <th><img src='../assets/img/gold.png'/>Rank</th>
        <th><i class='fa fa-user mr-1' style='color: #F4B806'></i>Members</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        <td>
           <div class='text-center'>                                                                                    
              <img src='images' alt='user dp'  class=' img-fluid  rounded-circle' style='height: 30px; width: 30px;' />                                                                                      
              <span class='mr-1 '>@$username</span>
          </div>
        <td>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody>
```

Expected output:

```
Rank    Member
1       image Dravid
2       image Richard Nixon
3       image GrahamBell
4       image Mark twains
```

Output's getting:

```
Rank    Member
1       image Dravid
2         image RichardNixon
3        image GrahamBell
4       image Mark twains
```

Comment: pick your solution: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/

Comment: Your table markup is invalid with no end to the `thead` or start to the `tbody` well, you have the data in the `thead` and not `tbody` and no `table` end tag - please try to reproduce the problem in your question - perhaps add the row examples from your output?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss ohh, I realized it was typo I mentioned mistakenly while asking question..My bad

Comment: Please edit your question to correct any typo or supply any updates that can clarify or facilitate the smallest code that reproduces the issue IN the question. 

Just a note, you can even include the CDN to the bootstrap in the code to reproduce it here directly on the RENDERED HTML right here in the question snippet code

Answer (score 1):

```css
img {margin-right:10px;};
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Rank</th>
      <th scope="col">Member</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td><img src="image"/>member</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td><img src="image"/>anotherMember</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td><img src="image"/>oneMoreMember</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please check your table markup, it doesn't seems to have any data in `<tbody>` . If you have to show the user image before the username place the `<img/>` inside the `<td>` tag just before the name of the member(in your case *username*). This will give you the alignment as per your need, no matter how long is the username **provided that the size(mostly width) of all the images is same**. I have included little CSS just to provide some space between **all** images and usernames. Also make sure this space remains constant for all images, if you wish to include it.

Comment: Thanx @Rohit for your answer and no doubt it's working. :)..Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using the `text-center` class on each `<tr>`'s second `<td>` (to display the username). That's because your those are centered accordingly resulting in this bug:

[image: Bug reproduction]

In order to solve this you have to replace it with `text-left` like in this example. The same for the second `<th>`. In order to place your item more to the right, apply a `padding-left`, e.g., by adding Bootstrap's `pl-5`:

```
<table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed"  class="table  table-striped text-center">
  <thead class='bg-dark' style='background-color: 3658DE'>
    <tr>
      <th><img src='https://via.placeholder.com/25'/> Rank</th>
      <th class="text-left pl-5"><i class='fa fa-user mr-1' style='color: #F4B806'></i>Members</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        1
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='text-left pl-5'>                                                                                    
          <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150' alt='user dp'  class='img-fluid  rounded-circle' style='height: 30px; width: 30px;' />                                                                                      
          <span class='mr-1 '>Dravid</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        2
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='text-left pl-5'>                                                                                    
          <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150' alt='user dp'  class='img-fluid  rounded-circle' style='height: 30px; width: 30px;' />                                                                                      
          <span class='mr-1 '>RichardNixon</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        3
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='text-left pl-5'>                                                                                    
          <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150' alt='user dp'  class='img-fluid  rounded-circle' style='height: 30px; width: 30px;' />                                                                                      
          <span class='mr-1 '>GrahamBell</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can find a [running fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/scebfwna/21/), which produces the following table:

[image: Resulting table]

Comment: Thanx @Tommy for your answer and no doubt it's working. :)..Cheers

Comment: @develper-base: Can you please mark an answer as correct so that the question is marked as completed?

Comment: I can, but when I try to do so, SO pops up this "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.".I used to upvote when someone answer my question but I guess S.O took the right from me to do so even for my own answer..!

Comment: You do not need to vote the answers, just press the checkmark icon. This should even work with 0 reputation.